# How to Send text messages browser to browser in webrtc?

Tags: p2p, webrtc

I want to send text messages directly to browser. Till now I'm only seeing the audio/video transmission demos in the web. These are my doubts:

- Can't we solve this just by using PeerConnection API?
- Or is the new DataChannel API is required to achieve this?
- If so, in which browser/browsers the dataChannel APIs are implemented?

Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Chrome canary supports DataChannel ... also firefox nightly: http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/data_test.html

Comment: "send text messages directly to browser" ?? browser to browser .... or simply "to browser" ? ....

Comment: @MuazKhan ya, browser to browser. Just like browser to browser video transmission in webrtc.

Comment: @MuazKhan and also that demo in mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/data_test.html doesn't seem to run  :( I'm using firefox nightly only.. What has to happen after I click Start button?

Comment: they used wrong variable...or missed it...you can see it in console...

Comment: This project (https://github.com/muaz-khan/ShareIt) also not worked for me...Personally I'm testing DataChannel APIs and when I get success...I'll upload here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment

Comment: @MuazKhan thanks :) So, we can't develop a chat like application without dataChannel API in webRTC?

Comment: As I know (I can be wrong) Google Chrome WebRTC team tested DataChannel APIs and they said it worked for them...they may release a simple demo soon... it means that for sure, you can design chatting app. However currently I've not found any working demo...you can post message on discuss-webrtc: groups.google.com/group/discuss-webrtc

Comment: You may like this: https://github.com/mozilla/socialapi-demo - http://mozilla.github.com/socialapi-demo/ - I "guess" DataChannel is being used there to send text and images...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Yes - you need to use dataChannel API

Its not cross-browser as they're still implementing it - I'd probably use socket.io with node atm for a cross-browser app.

Once datachannel is done, it'll be AMAZING! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the DataChannel part of of the PeerConnection API. This will work in firefox 18 and forward and is coming to Chrome some time soon.

A good starting point to understand how to do this is https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/progress-update-on-webrtc-for-firefox-on-desktop/ and the latest draft of the specification at http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html!

Answer (score 3):

There are some JavaScript libraries for sending text data using WebRTC Data Channel API: [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com), [webRTC.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io), [DataChannel.io](https://github.com/marcolanaro/DataChannel.IO), [BoneValue](https://github.com/theninj4/bonevalue)... (add more if you know)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about text messages, why not use the WebSocket API instead, which has a much broader support range?

Comment: But WebRTC is much faster than websockets no? And also im not interested in just a chat messages.. More concerned abt sending application data in real time.

Comment: You can safely use WebRTC Data Channel API with WebSockets [fallback](https://github.com/piranna/DataChannel-polyfill).